# Error encountered could not complete yarn install of substrate front end template

Tags: node.js, blockchain, substrate, polkadot

Followed the installation steps provided here

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/create-your-first-substrate-chain/

Steps taken with node version v16.14.0

```
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template
yarn install
```

Error code

```
Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.0 [e199f] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-syntax-flow (p79568), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.0 [e199f] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx (p2880e), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:12.0.0 doesn't provide typescript (p08c91), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:12.0.0 doesn't provide webpack (pf80ce), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-scripts@npm:5.0.0 [9c894] doesn't provide autoprefixer (peca2e), requested by tailwindcss
➤ YN0060: │ react-scripts@npm:5.0.0 [9c894] provides eslint (p3d1f2) with version 8.6.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app and some of its descendants request
➤ YN0002: │ substrate-front-end-template@workspace:. doesn't provide eslint (p83184), requested by eslint-config-prettier
➤ YN0002: │ substrate-front-end-template@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack (p9e29f), requested by node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 245ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ semantic-ui-css@https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS.git#commit=01e4a5346496c284db3b19a102458731ccccd911 can't be found in the cache and will be fe
➤ YN0013: │ semantic-ui-css@https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS.git#commit=01e4a5346496c284db3b19a102458731ccccd911 can't be found in the cache and will be fe
➤ YN0018: │ semantic-ui-css@https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS.git#commit=01e4a5346496c284db3b19a102458731ccccd911: The remote archive doesn't match the expected checksum
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 8s 74ms
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 8s 327ms
```

Answer (score 27):

Resolved it by performing these steps

```
yarn cache clean --all
yarn install
```

At this point, got the same error. Then run this:

```
YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn
```

Credits to answer from [Github discussion](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1142#issuecomment-607272809)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this

```
yarn cache clean --all
```

but the issue was that after a rebase, the yarn lock file had been completely mixed up, making the install fail regardless.
I deleted the `yarn.lock` file and `.node-module` folder and ran `yarn install` again:

```
rmdir .node-modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn install
```